# Eclipse JUnit Test Only Running Once

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am having some troubles with eclipse. I am trying to run a JUnit Test file to test my file. It has 11 parts but only the first part will run. Could anyone assist me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's still running to me, since the Stop button is red (turns gray on completion). Log your second test to see what's going on. Might be an infinite loop.

Comment: If that doesn't work, just provide the method for that test.

Comment: Try to run each method separately first before you execute everything. Post the exact error you getting while running the JUnit methods.

Comment: Debug the test rather than Run it; you'll then be able to suspend the VM in from the Debug view and see what it's still doing.